# What's the difference between Data Exchange Framework and xConnect?

Tags: sitecore-client, data-exchange-framework

The title says it all really. I've heard both terms used interchangeably.

I'm assuming the DEF is the underlying framework, and xConnect is built on top of that, and it is xConnect that allows you to configure endpoints and integrations from within the Sitecore client.

Will Sitecore 8.3 be required for both, or is it just xConnect we have to wait for?

Could somebody confirm, or point me to somewhere that distinguishes the two?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be helpful http://phani-abburi.blogspot.com/2016/11/a-primer-on-sitecore-data-exchange.html

Comment: I provided this as an answer to another post, giving an overview of what DXF is, what it can do and how to get started with it. Not an answer, but you might find it useful: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/5171/423

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data Exchange Framework is an ETL tool that is configured using Sitecore. It provides the ability to define synchronization processes that read data from a source system, transform the data into a format that is compatible with a target system, then write the transformed data to the target system.

xConnect is a new API for getting data in and out of xDB. It makes accessing xDB data much easier, consistent, and scalable than in the past.

They are independent but complementary products. A DEF provider will be available so you can use xConnect as a source or target system.